# can't pass data in asp.net mvc controller from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller in asp.net mvc , i just want to pass an array of javascript object from local storage to my controller method for showing the result of products present in cart

here is my controller code

```
//shopping cart
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Cart(JsonResult[] list)
        {

            //my code for list object

            return View();
        }
```

and here is my code for client side

```
window.addEventListener('load', init);

function init()
{
    showcart();


    var ls = window.localStorage.getItem('cart');

    if(ls === null)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        var cart = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('cart'));

        $.post("/Home/Cart",
        cart,
        function(data, status){
            alert("Status: " + status);
        });
    }


}
```

can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong

Comment: you need to use ionic frame work

Answer (score 0):

You should go with [NativeScript Documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/) It is an open-source framework to develop apps on the Apple iOS and Android platforms. And it's pretty much interesting too. I hope you will also find it interesting.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many options. Most popular ones are [`Ionic`](https://ionicframework.com/)and [`Native script`](https://www.nativescript.org/). and if you want to go with react you can use [`React native`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/). If you are familiar with *angular* , *typescript* you better go with *Ionic*.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is used in Ionic and Nativescript. Nativescript apps are faster since they are truly native apps. Also documentation is really good and community forums are very active